# AngularJS - is it possible to have underscore in directive's name?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, naming-conventions

I have problem with angular directive's naming convention and the way angular normalize my directives names.
In order to follow some naming conventions in an existing project, to which I want to add angular, I need to name my custom directive with "_" in such manner:

```
app.directive("directive_name", function(...) {...});
```

Sadly doing so seems to contradict with Angular's way of normalization of directive's name and as a result such directives are ignored, not compiled and hence not shown on the screen.

[Question]
Is it possible to name a directive in such way that later we can use it in the HTML as follows:

```
<body>
    ...
    <my_directive></my_directive>
</body>
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can have low dash on your directive name, you just have to write your directive name like always:

```
app.directive("yourDirectiveName", function(...) {...});
```

and than only in your code use the low dash:

```
<your_directive_name></your_directive_name>
```

Maybe depends on the version of angularjs you are using but the match between your html tag name and the directive name is made by the jqLite function camelCase

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.x/src/jqLite.js#L106

as you can see you can use low dash because of the regexp used:

```
SPECIAL_CHARS_REGEXP = /([\:\-\_]+(.))/g;
```

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. I have always used camelCase notation, I just didn't know angular will accept both '-' and '_' in the HTML. Strangly it never occur to me to just try... Couldn'e expect it to work without any effort on my side. THANKS.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is possible, but you need declare it in camelCase:

```
app.directive("directiveName", function(...) {...});
```

html

```
<my_directive></my_directive>
```

but imho - better, use dashes

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

Actually angular will normalize directive names from html as following:

1. Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
2. Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to camelCase.

Comment: Exactly my answer.. More on this here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. I have always used camelCase notation, I just didn't know angular will accept both '-' and '_' in the HTML. Strangly it never occur to me to just try... Couldn'e expect it to work without any effort on my side. THANKS +1. I accepted markov00's answer because it may give some more information for anyone that might need it later!